# GNU parallel array argument

Tags: python, gnu-parallel

Suppose I have a python file `test.py`:

```
import os

class print_args(object):

    def__init__(self, x, y, z):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

        print(x)
        print(y)
        print(z)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--x', nargs='+', type = str)
    parser.add_argument('--y', nargs='+', type = int)
    parser.add_argument('--z', type = int)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print_args(args.x, args.y, args.z)
```

I can run `test.py` from the terminal with arguments as follows:

```
python3 test.py --x a b --y 2 3 --z 10
```

The results are as expected:

```
a b
2 3
10
```

**How do I run `test.py` using GNU parallel in the terminal with array arguments?** The solution would be equivalent to running:

```
python3 test.py --x a b --y 2 3 --z 10
python3 test.py --x a b --y 2 3 --z 20 
python3 test.py --x a b --y 2 3 --z 30
python3 test.py --x a b --y 2 3 --z 40
```

My incorrect attempt at answering my own question is:

```
parallel --link 'python3 test.py --x {1} --y {2} --z {3}' ::: \
> 'a b' 'a b' 'a b' 'a b' ::: \
> '2 3' '2 3' '2 3' '2 3' ::: \
> '10' '20' '30' '40'
```

Comment: Do you mean `parallel -k echo --x "a b" --y "2 3" --z ::: 10 20 30 40`

Comment: How does your solution work with `test.py`?

Comment: Replace `echo` with `python3 test.py`

Comment: `parallel -k --dry-run python3 test.py --x "a b" --y "2 3" --z ::: 10 20 30 40`

Comment: Any joy with that? Or are you still having problems?

Comment: It works, thank-you. Can you write your comment as an answer so I can accept it as the best solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully, as discussed in the comments, this works for you:

```
parallel -k --dry-run python3 test.py --x "a b" --y "2 3" --z ::: 10 20 30 40
```

**Sample Output**

```
python3 test.py --x a b --y 2 3 --z 10
python3 test.py --x a b --y 2 3 --z 20
python3 test.py --x a b --y 2 3 --z 30
python3 test.py --x a b --y 2 3 --z 40
```

Remove the `--dry-run` part if the command looks good, then run it again for real.